# Is there a general 'form' for the angle of a 2D vector?

Tags: reference-frames, vectors, coordinate-systems, conventions, notation

Just like the magnitude of a vector can be represented by $|\vec{v}|$, is there a general way to represent the angle?

I.e. a shorter way than $tan^{-1}(\frac{v_y}{v_x})$.

Comment: Is $\vec{v}_\theta$ a thing?

Comment: $\angle \vec{v}$? (made with `\angle`).

Comment: Note that $\tan \left(\frac{v_y}{v_x}\right)$ is *not* the angle of $\vec{v}$ (which I often write as $\theta_v$): it is *either* the angle of $\vec{v}$ or the angle opposite that of $\vec{v}$. In many computer environments you can use `atan2`, but in general you have to examine the signs of the components yourself.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you, I totally blanked out there. That works!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because $\vec v=(v_x,v_y)\implies\vec v=(\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2},\tan^{-1}(\frac{v_y}{v_x})+c)=(v_r,v_\theta)$. So the "shortest" way would be $v_\theta$ (or simply $\theta$), which is simply the angle of $\vec v$.

Answer (score 0):

In 2D or complex numbers: $\arg(\vec{v})$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)